# Using sum with chartkick on multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js, chartkick

I want to display the chart of revenue which is `total * quantity`

I can do charts like this to display the total:

```
<%= line_chart @line_items_sold.group_by_day(:created_at).sum(:total) %>
```

Although doing sum with multiple attributes:

```
<%= line_chart @line_items_sold.group_by_day(:created_at).sum{|li| li.store_price.to_d * li.store_fulfillable_quantity} %>
```

doesn't work...

error:
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "line_items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Doing:

```
<%= line_chart @line_items_sold.sum{|li| li.store_price.to_d * li.store_fulfillable_quantity}.group_by_day(:created_at) %>
```

Error: Can't group_by *n*BigDecimal

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

I want to show the revenue (price * quantity) on a per day basis.

Comment: May you check `@line_items_sold.group_by_day(&:created_at).sum(:total)` works?

Comment: Could you update with some sample data please? The result of `@line_items_sold.group_by_day(:created_at)` would be very handy.

Comment: @RishiPithadiya sorry for delay::: That gives error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for :store_fulfillable_quantity:Symbol)`

Comment: @SRack Error: `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "line_items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` ..... @line_items_sold is LineItem.all

Comment: Currently, my only work around is making this a decimal in the dtabase itself on Record Creation but eh.  Any thoughts?